# In EntityFramework Core : Multiple requests cause Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am adding new record into a table using EntityFramework core 
as the following :
[image]

```
public void AddAudit(Audit audit)
    {
        foodStoreDBContext.Audits.Add(audit);
        foodStoreDBContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

. When executing this statement causing no issue but when I tried to call this function using concurrent requests for testing purpose (around 10 concurrent requests ) repeated 100 times then exception is shown :
"this sqltransaction has completed; it is no longer usable. "

I register the DatabaseContext class in Scope :

```
services.AddScoped<IAuditRepository, AuditRepository>();
```

even though I changed to AddTransiant ,still having an issue .

one of the recommendation is enabling retry on Failure like this :

```
the configuration I am using are :

options.UseSqlServer(
           Configuration["Data:FoodSave:ConnectionString"],sqlServerOptionsAction: sqlOptions =>
           {
               sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(
               maxRetryCount: 10,
               maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
               errorNumbersToAdd: null);
           })
```

but still have the same error above   .
please help

Comment: How do you call this code concurrently? Can you show us that too?

Comment: Using Test Tool JMETER  , putting Number of threads : 10

Comment: Since you use JMETER That means each request has different context.

Comment: How do you add EfContext to DI?

Comment: Have you called `foodStoreDBContext.SaveChanges();` multiple times in different places? Check the output windows to see whether there is any error while comminting the process.

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat , I add as the following  ` services.AddDbContext<FoodStoreDBContext>(options =>
           options.UseSqlServer(
           Configuration["Data:FoodSave:ConnectionString"],sqlServerOptionsAction: sqlOptions =>
           {
               sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(
               maxRetryCount: 10,
               maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
               errorNumbersToAdd: null);
           })`  .@TaoZhou I am calling from one place in my code (within an action and this action called multiple times as HTTP Requests "using JMETER Testing tool"